# Grid layout with auto columns resize with a full-width flex child

Tags: css, grid-layout

I have created a table with expandable rows using CSS Grid Layout and everything works fine until I add an element with a flex layout in the expandable section.

The expandable section use a grid-column: 1/-1; and the content should not affect the rest of the grid or that is what i thought.

I have created a simplified version to show the problem:

```js
function toggle() {
  const elem = document.querySelector('.all-columns');
  if (elem.style.display === "none") {
    elem.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  width: 400px;
}

.row {
  display: contents;
}

.all-columns {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex-child {
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">Row1 Column1</div>
    <div class="column">Row1 Column2 with large name</div>
    <div class="column">Row1 Column3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="all-columns">
      <div class="flex-child">1 flex</div>
      <div class="flex-child">2 flex</div>
      <div class="flex-child">3 flex</div>
      <div class="flex-child">4 flex</div>
      <div class="flex-child">5 flex</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">Row3 Column1</div>
    <div class="column">Row4 Column2</div>
    <div class="column">Row1 Column3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle expandable section</button>
```

As you can see, the size of the middle column changes when the expandable section is shown/hide.

The content of the expandable section  is external so I cannot modify it at all.
I have tested it in Firefox and Chrome with the same result.

I'd appreciate if someone has an explanation for this behaviour.

Thanks.

Comment: Since the columns are `auto` the content of `.all-columns` ends up wider than the grid `400px` So everything is pushed to accommodate that then `flex-wrap` kicks in last to wrap, If you're sure of the `400px` just add it as a fixed width on `.all-columns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `width: 0;min-width: 100%;` to all-columns so it won't contribute to defining the width and won't affect the other elements:

```js
function toggle() {
  const elem = document.querySelector('.all-columns');
  if (elem.style.display === "none") {
    elem.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  width: 400px;
}

.row {
  display: contents;
}

.all-columns {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex-child {
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">Row1 Column1</div>
    <div class="column">Row1 Column2 with large name</div>
    <div class="column">Row1 Column3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="all-columns">
      <div class="flex-child">1 flex</div>
      <div class="flex-child">2 flex</div>
      <div class="flex-child">3 flex</div>
      <div class="flex-child">4 flex</div>
      <div class="flex-child">5 flex</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">Row3 Column1</div>
    <div class="column">Row4 Column2</div>
    <div class="column">Row1 Column3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle expandable section</button>
```

Comment: Do you know why exactly we need to to add those rules? I guess the width: 0 make the grid ignore the child for some internal size calculation and the min-width overwrites  the width so the element fit the whole row but since the `.all-columns` fit the all columns (from 1 to -1), Is the resize the expected behaviour in a Grid Layout or is the browser not calculating the size of the columns properly?

Comment: @JesusBarcenilla you have 2 component, the child and the grid tracks. By settings width;0 the child is ignored in the calculation like you said and the browser will define the width of the tracks (the columns, rows) then you set the child to take all the columns (grid-column:1/-1). Until now, we have a width:0 element place inside all the columns (that have definite size). Finally we force the child to have the width of all the columns using min-width:100% (100% will refer to the track where the child is).

Comment: @JesusBarcenilla I wrote a small article about this trick: https://dev.to/afif/responsive-text-based-on-image-size-36n9 .. it works in a lot of cases